# Prove that $|A\times B| = |B\times A|$ for any infinte sets $A,B$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

> Prove that $|A\times B| = |B\times A|$ for any infinte sets $A,B$

I tried to build $f:(A\times B) \to B\times A$ that takes $(a_i,b_i)$ and return the opposite $(b_i,a_i)$, but I'm not sure its right.

Comment: That function does the trick, so yes.

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: how can i explain that the function is onto BXA?

Answer (score 2):

Your idea is good. Let $f : A \times B \to B \times A$ be defined by $f((a,b)):=(b,a).$

Are you able to show that $f$ is injective ?

$f$ is onto: to this end let $(u,v) \in B \times A$. Then $(v,u) \in A \times B$ and $f((v,u))=(u,v).$

Answer (score 0):

You can make a far more general claim, as follows: given a family of sets $A$ indexed by set $I$ and an arbitrary permutation $\sigma \in \Sigma(I)$ (the latter denoting **the set of all bijections from** $I$ **to itself**), then one has:

> $$\prod_{i \in I}\ A_{i} \approx \prod_{i \in I}\ A_{\sigma(i)}\ (\mathrm{Ens})$$

where for arbitrary sets $X, Y$ the relation $X \approx Y\ (\mathrm{Ens})$ means the two are isomorphic in $\mathrm{Ens}$, **the category of sets**, in other words there exists a bijection between them.

By the very nature of the cartesian product, one can construct a natural pair of mutually inverse bijections that will establish the stated isomorphism of sets. For arbitrary $i \in I$ define $$p_{i}: \prod_{j \in I}\ A_{j} \to A_{i}$$ as the $i$-projection of the left-hand side cartesian product and $$p'_{i}: \prod_{j \in I}\ A_{\sigma(j)} \to A_{\sigma(i)}$$ the analogous projection for the right-hand side cartesian product (the $i$-projection assigns to every element $x$ in the respective cartesian product its $i$-component). Furthermore, let us define maps$$q_{i}=p_{\sigma(i)},\\ q'_{i}=p'_{\sigma^{-1}(i)}$$

By **the universality property of cartesian products**, there will exist two maps
$$f: \prod_{i \in I}\ A_{i} \to \prod_{i \in I}\ A_{\sigma(i)},\\ g: \prod_{i \in I}\ A_{\sigma(i)} \to \prod_{i \in I}\ A_{i}$$ unique with the respective properties that for every $i \in I$ one has $p'_{i} \circ f=q_i,\ p_i \circ g=q'_{i}$. From this point on it is easy to verify that: 
$$p_i \circ g \circ f=q'_i \circ f=p'_{\sigma^{-1}(i)} \circ f=q_{\sigma^{-1}(i)}=p_i$$ and similarly $$p'_i \circ f \circ g=q_i \circ g=p_{\sigma(i)} \circ g=q'_{\sigma(i)}=p'_i$$ for every index $i$, fact which entails the conclusion that $$f \circ g=\mathbf{1}_{\prod_{i \in I}\ A_{\sigma(i)}},\\ g \circ f=\mathbf{1}_{\prod_{i \in I}\ A_i}$$

In your particular case, this general result can be applied for a family of sets $C$ indexed by the set $\{1, 2\}$, such that $C_1=A,\ C_2=B$ together with the transposition $(12)$ (the only nontrivial permutation of the given two-element set, the one that swaps $1$ with $2$). According to the general argument, you obtain bijection $f: A \times B \to B \times A$ given by the correspondence law $f(x,y)=(y,x)$. It is immediately verified that $f$ **is its own inverse** (what we call an involution), and that is the most direct way to settle the matter, rather than argue individually about injectivity and surjectivity.